# Правка утверждена/отклонена

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, предлагаемые-правки

> Данная ожидающая правка уже была утверждена/отклонена.
> Пожалуйста, обновите страницу, чтобы отобразить изменения.

Не нравится мне это сообщение, переформулируем?

---

Оригинальные строки из transifex:

> [This pending edit has already been approved/rejected.](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265425?key=09e2f5f8b59c30d7d2c4388dc7a9b749)
>
> [Please refresh the page to see any changes.](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265435?key=c3766df7944242a019250421921f030b)

Comment: Подобные предложения хорошо бы дополнять скриншотами, чтобы понимать как оно выглядит по месту и не нужно ли будет менять что-то рядом. Если есть возможность, пожалуйста, добавьте к вопросу.

Comment: @alexolut, скриншот не сделал. Красная плашка, такая же, как при "произошла ошибка".

Answer (score 10):

Вообще надо вычеркнуть этот канцелярит - "ожидающая", это то же самое, что и "данная". Нора Галь рекомендовала бы простой и понятный вариант: "эта правка". Всё, достаточно.

И ещё -- избавляемся от страдательного залога "была обработана":

> Эту правку уже обработали.
>
> Пожалуйста, обновите страницу, чтобы увидеть изменения.

или:

> Эта правка уже обработана.
>
> Пожалуйста, обновите страницу, чтобы увидеть изменения.

Comment: _"Эта правка уже обработана."_ - я за эту версию

Comment: Точно, страдательный залог не нужен. Я за первый вариант. Кстати, наверное стоит разделить их, а то непонятно, за что голосуют.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не переживайте, у нас есть специалист, отвечающий за локализаторский произвол )) Он и выберет.

Comment: Мне не очень нравится, когда перевод допускает новые толкования. В частности замена "утверждена/отклонена" на "обработана". Если это взаимозаменяемые понятия, то лучше изменить оригинал (хотя это вопрос уже для других инстанций), чем додумывать что-то в переводе.

Comment: @alexolut Толковое замечание. Почему вообще заменялось "утверждена/отклонена": потому что хотелось избежать лишнего канцелярита когда "пишут роботы": "Уважаемый(ая) Виктор Иванович!" Мы не можем повлиять на то, чтобы появилось на английском две отдельных строки (одна для reject, другая для approve), но можем выбрать слово, которое объединяет эти два действия. Мы обработали эту правку, она принята/отклонена. По-моему, очевидное и понятное объединения. Мы обязаны дословно воспроизводить в переводе оригинальный тест? Нет. Полагаю, что и тут можем чуть отступить от общего правила.

Comment: @AK отступить можем, если это не нарушит смысла. Т.е. если `утверждена/отклонена` тождественно равно `обработана`. Просто как-то уже отступили и перевели `duplicate of...` как `этот вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение…`. А потом появились [вопросы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4001/176217). Вот такого хочется избежать.

Comment: @alexolut Скорее не тождественно равна. И, раз есть сомнения, может оставим (пока?) немного канцелярита? Виды обработки бывают разные, они не обязаны совпадать с "утверждена/отклонена". Лично моё мнение, что посетителям будет понятно, всё-таки на эту очередь нужно 2к репутации, люди уже понимают что к чему к этому моменту. Но риск который вы опасаетесь вполне понятен.

Answer (score 2):

ИО "ходячего тезауруса" спешит на помощь.

> Эта правка уже рассмотрена.
>
> Пожалуйста, обновите страницу, чтобы увидеть изменения.

Answer (score 0):

> Ожидающая правка уже была обработана.
>   Пожалуйста, обновите страницу, чтобы увидеть изменения.

Что поменял:

- Данная ожидающая => Ожидающая
- утверждена/отклонена => обработана
- отобразить => увидеть